# alloy-ui how do I limit the displayed time in the scheduler

Tags: scheduler, alloy-ui

Using this scheduler http://alloyui.com/tutorials/scheduler/ how do I limit the displayed time to between 10am to 7pm (10:00 to 19:00) instead of 12am to 11pm (00:00 to 23:59), in the week and day views?

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/blob/master/src/aui-scheduler/js/aui-scheduler-view-day.js) it appears the default implementation is strongly coupled to an assumed `24` hour format. I started [an implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/tm8m1wk0/1/) but it currently has issues with component rendering which I attribute to the coupling.

Comment: I see. Do you think it would be possible to edit the source code until it supports this, and then posting a pull request? Unfortunately I don't think I'm good enough at JS yet to do that.

Comment: @Divran, there is a [sample git repo](https://github.com/brandizzi/aui-scheduler-view-resources) which shows how to do some deeper changes to scheduler views.

Comment: @stiemannkj1 I ended up writing my own scheduler from scratch, but that reply may help other people looking for the same thing, so thanks